# Cis-Trans Isomers Heat of Combustion

Tags: stability, heat, isomers

[image]

> Consider the 4 cis-trans isomers for the above compound. In what way
>   would the cis-trans isomers affect their heat of combustion.

I think that if the substituents are on alternating sides of the ring, then there will be minimum steric crowding. But is there anything else that would affect their heat of combustions?

UPDATE: Here is as far as I have gotten. Now I think for the methyl group on carbon 4, either conformation would be stable. I am guessing that an axial methyl group would be more stable, because the axial position is free from all types of steric repulsion (This is just a guess). Is this correct?

[image]

Comment: You need to consider the conformation of the ring.

Comment: The t-butyl group will be equatorial then draw the possible diastereomers. Read this: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/118093/low-or-high-enthalpy-of-combustion-in-relation-to-stability/118130#118130

Comment: @user55119 is it true that whenever we have a single group attached on a cyclohexane, it will take an equatorial position? And if we have more than one group, the most bulky group takes the equatorial position

Comment: No. For a single group on cyclohexane it is an equilibrium as a function of its effective size. The larger the group, the more equatorial. t-Butyl is essentially always equatorial. This might help: http://ursula.chem.yale.edu/~chem220/chem220js/STUDYAIDS i/Avalues.htm

Comment: @user55119 OK, so after that what do we do?

Comment: Do you realize that all 4 isomers give the same amount of CO2 and H2O on combustion? The more stable the isomer, the less the heat of combustion. Your job, not WE, is to draw all four and make a conclusion.

Comment: @user55119 I drew all four of them, but I still don't know what to do with one of the methyl groups. See my update in my question.

Comment: Is there a penalty for an axial methyl group? Are there any gauche t-butyl/methyl interactions? Make an effort to solve this qualitatively and amend your post before I would provide an answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107960/discussion-between-gauri-agrawal-and-user55119).